# Change knockout.js optionsText depending on its selected status

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to make the text of an  element vary depending on whether or not it's selected, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to reference the parent object to determine which object is selected.

Simplified example of what I'm trying to work off:

```js
function Model(items){
    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);
    this.selectedItem = ko.observable();
    this.dropDownText = function(item){
        if(this.selectedItem()===item){
            return item.name;
        }else{
            return item.dropDownText;
        }
    }
}

function Item(name, price){
    this.name=name;
    this.price=price;
    this.dropDownText=name + ' ($' + price + ')';
    this.dropDownTextFunction = function(item){
        return item.name + ' ($' + item.price + ')';
    }
}

var m = new Model([new Item('hammer', 5), new Item('nail', 0.03), new Item('tooth', 0.6)]);
m.selectedItem(m.items()[1]);
ko.applyBindings(m);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: items(), value: selectedItem, optionsText: 'dropDownText'"></select>
<span data-bind="text: selectedItem().price"></span>
```

The price should not be displayed in the selected  element, but it should be for the others.

What I've tried:

- 'dropDownText' - non-function variables work fine, but this doesn't solve the problem
- 'dropDownTextFunction' - displays the function's code in the dropdown, also no way to get to the parent object
- 'dropDownTextFunction()' - results in empty option text, again no way to get to the parent object
- '$parent.dropDownText' - also results in empty option text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one solution, but not the one I'd prefer to implement in my ko app.

```js
function Model(items){
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray(items);
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
  
    self.selectedItem.subscribe(function() {
      console.log('Selected');
      items.forEach(function(it) {
        if (it === self.selectedItem()) {
          it.dropDownText(it.name);
        } else {
          it.dropDownText(it.name + ' ($' + it.price + ')');
        }
      });
    });
  
    
    return self;
}

function Item(name, price){
    this.name=name;
    this.price=price;
    this.dropDownText= ko.observable(name + ' ($' + price + ')');
}

var m = new Model([new Item('hammer', 5), new Item('nail', 0.03), new Item('tooth', 0.6)]);
m.selectedItem(m.items()[1]);
ko.applyBindings(m);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: items(), value: selectedItem, optionsText: 'dropDownText'"></select>
<span data-bind="text: selectedItem().price"></span>
```

One completely necessary thing is that the `dropDownText` is observable, so that the displayed text can be updated when it changes. That was missing in your original code.

The part that I don't like is having to compute the observable for the whole list whenever the selected value changes.

An alternative would be to modify the item object and the subscription, which makes it a little cleaner:

```
function Model(items){
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray(items);
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
    self.selectedItem.subscribe(function() {
      items.forEach(function(it) {
        it.selected(it === self.selectedItem())
      });
    });    
    return self;
}

function Item(name, price){
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.price = price;
    self.selected = ko.observable(false);
    self.dropDownText = ko.computed(function() {
      return this.selected()
          ? this.name : this.name + ' ($' + this.price + ')';
    },self);
    return self;
}
```

But what I'd really prefere would be to let the viewmodel handle the whole creation and management of items. You could create a model with a function which could be invoked like `model.addItem(name,price)` or another like this `additems([{name: '', price:1}, ...])`. If you try this path you'll see that implementing the view model is extremely clear and easy, because the model taks care of itself and all of its components. You could also expose the cosntructor in the model, if you want to use it from the other code.

*NOTE: the `var self=this` pattern simplifies working with `this` in other funcions in the model, like the computed observables*

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, and the clarification of `self` which I was about to ask about! The model I'm actually working with precludes your last (`addItem`) solution, but the second one (alternative) will do fine.

Comment: Now that you mention it, if you read the docs on ko computed you'll see that self is passed as second parameter on the `computed` so that it's accesible as `this` from within the provided function body. In JavaScript `this` is difficult to handle, because the value of `this` depends on how you call the function: generally `this` refers to the object from which you invoke the function. Besides you can change the value of `this` by using `apply`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply